# How to compare if a folder's last modified date matches the current date? VBA

Tags: vba

I have a program that will look for a specific file in a folder and if it exists, it will copy that file into a designated file path. I would like to go one step further and take my current code and have a check that happens prior to it. This check would be looking at a specified folder and determine if it's last modified date matches today's date. If the specified folder's last modified date matches the current date, I would like for the code to go into that folder and then my current code would execute.

```
Sub sbCopyingAFile()

'Declare Variables
Dim FSO
Dim sFile As String
Dim sSFolder As String
Dim sDFolder As String

'This is Your File Name which you want to Copy
sFile = "testfile.xlsx"

'Change to match the source folder path
sSFolder = "C:\Dropbox (###)\BD SQL\"

'Change to match the destination folder path
sDFolder = "C:\Dropbox (###)\BD SQL\testpath\"

'Create Object
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Checking If File Is Located in the Source Folder
If Not FSO.FileExists(sSFolder & sFile) Then
    MsgBox "Specified File Not Found", vbInformation, "Not Found"
    
'Copying If the Same File is Not Located in the Destination Folder
ElseIf Not FSO.FileExists(sDFolder & sFile) Then
    FSO.CopyFile (sSFolder & sFile), sDFolder, True
    MsgBox "Specified File Copied Successfully", vbInformation, "Done!"
Else
    MsgBox "Specified File Already Exists In The Destination Folder", vbExclamation, "File Already Exists"
End If

Debug.Print (sSFolder & sFile)

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next function:

```
Function GetDateLastModif(strFold As String) As Date
   Dim fso As Object, gf As Object
   Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
   Set gf = fso.GetFolder(strFold)
   GetDateLastModif = gf.DateLastModified
End Function
```

It can be tested as:

```
Debug.Print GetDateLastModif(ThisWorkbook.path) 'with or without the ending backslash
```

Or, having `fso` object already, you may use `GetFolder` it in your existing code:

```
     Dim gf As Object, d As Date
     Set gf = fso.GetFolder(sSFolder)
     d = gf.DateLastModified
     If DateSerial(Year(d), month(d), Day(d)) = Date Then
        'do whatever you need...
     End If
```

You can also use the next (simpler) way:

```
    If CLng(cg.DateLastModified) = Date Then 'eliminate the decimals!
        'do what you want
     End If
```

But the most elegant solution would be to compare them directly. Based of the fact that `DateLastModified` cannot be a date from the future. It will be (in terms of `Single`/`Double` values) bigger or equal to current date due to the hours:minutes:seconds "contribution"...

```
     If gf.DateLastModified >= Date Then  
         'do what you need...
     End If
```

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, thank you for the response. So as you mentioned, since I already have the fso object declared, I went ahead and opted to use the bottom code that you suggested. I was testing to see if that **Day(gf.DateLastModified) = Date** would work and it didn't, but that's because I needed to add on more to it. Since date returns mm/dd/yyyy, I went and used the **Month** and **Year** functions as well and concatenated them all into a string and then compared and got the desired result. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @bgado Glad I could help! Theoretically, `DateLastModified` returns time, where form the code tries to extract only the day. Format should not matter. Is your localization different than standard English?

Comment: No, my localization is set to standard English. So, my apologies but I'm a bit lost, if DateLastModified returns time and the code only extracts the day, let's say the folder's day is 08, and you compare that to Date, wouldn't the equation be **08 = Today[11/12/2021]** ? This is how I'm understanding how that process is working, aided by using handy debug.print. Feel free to correct me if I'm out of bounds.

Comment: @bgado Ups... Of course, you are right. What inattentive I could be. I was so convinced that I made it return/extract the `Date` then I didn't even think about the possibility of a mistake, in such a simple code line. I will open my laptop in some minutes and I need to supply at least two more elegant solutions... The first one crossing my head is comparing them directly... :)